# Array variable link to another page

Tags: php, html, arrays

Currently I am stuck. I have to get an overview of domains. These have to link to an record page. The problem is, I don't know how. I have tried to set an $_SESSION, but then it picks the first variable of my array. At the moment things are hardcoded with 1 example.

```html
<?php

unset($command);
$command = array(
"command" => "DomainsListActive"
);

$api = new Versio_api();
$versio = $api->api_send($command);

if($versio['success']==0) {
echo("Fout opgetreden. Fout code: ".$versio['command_response_code'].". Fout text: ".$versio['command_response_message']."");
}
else {
if($versio['total_count']>0)
{
require_once("includes/submenu.php");
?>
<div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9" style="width:80%;">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Klantenpaneel</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form method="post" action="">
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Domein</th>
              <th>TLD</th>
              <th>Verloop datum</th>
              <th>Automatisch verlengen</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <tbody>
              <?php 
$teller = 1;
while($versio['total_count']>=$teller) {
?>
              <tr>
                <td><?php echo $versio['id_'.$teller]; ?></td> 
                <td><a href="records.php"><?php echo $versio['domain_'.$teller]; ?></a> </td>
                <td><?php echo $versio['tld_'.$teller]; ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $versio['expiration_date_'.$teller]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $versio['auto_renew_'.$teller]; ?></td>
              </tr>
<?php $teller++; } ?> 
            </tbody>
          </table>
          </form>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
  } else {
    echo("Er zijn geen DNS records gevonden voor dit domein.");
  }
}
?>
```

I have to get for example, the third variable of $versio['domain_'.$teller] to put in my array in antoher document, record.php. If there is somebody who could help me that would be awesome!

Comment: Are you using MySQL?

Comment: I am using PDO.

Comment: Show that code please. You are doing it totally wrong.

Comment: Working with an API of Versio to get that overview.

Comment: Show your code as @praveen kumar asked that will help people to give an answer

Comment: Yes, it is better to update your full code for now rather than chat. You need some rep to chat here.

Comment: @PraveenKumar i will update the code

Comment: OKay, looks like you might need to provide more information for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, could you pass the variables in a query string?

eg:

```
<a href="records.php?domain=<?php echo $versio['domain_'.$teller]; ?>&tld=<?php echo $versio['tld_'.$teller]; ?>">
    <?php echo $versio['domain_'.$teller]; ?>
</a>
```

Then in records.php you could get those values with:

```
<?php

$domain = $_GET['domain'];
$tld = $_GET['tld'];
```

Comment: My friend, you're my hero!